# React And Django

Tags: reactjs, django

hello friends please need you help in this one
developing a lead manager app with react django rest_frame
when i run server it runs fine
but when i run this certain command (npm run dev) i get

npm run dev

> lead_manager_react_django@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\SterlingTech\Desktop\lead_manager_react_django
> webpack --mode development ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js

[webpack-cli] Unknown argument: --output
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! lead_manager_react_django@1.0.0 dev: `webpack --mode development ./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js --output ./leadmanager/frontend/static/frontend/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lead_manager_react_django@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SterlingTech\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-11T10_02_30_863Z-debug.log

(lead_manager_react_django-tk_lVMTa) C:\Users\SterlingTech\Desktop\lead_manager_react_django>python manage.py
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\SterlingTech\Desktop\lead_manager_react_django\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

please help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webpack-cli Unknown argument: --output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791687/webpack-cli-unknown-argument-output)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `--output-path` argument instead of just `--output` or just `-o` as it's written in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#flags). By the way your question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791687/webpack-cli-unknown-argument-output) already.

Comment: @OlumideAbiodun You're welcome, would be good if you mark the answer as accepted also.