# webpack-cli Unknown argument: --output

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

My npm, node js versions:

[image]

When I try to run the `npm dev` command:

[image]

The log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle winteka@1.0.0~predev: winteka@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle winteka@1.0.0~dev: winteka@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle winteka@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle winteka@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/dziugas/winteka/node_modules/.bin:/home/dziugas/.local/share/virtualenvs/winteka-rp-_dylZ/bin:/home/dziugas/.vscode-server/bin/fcac248b077b55bae4ba5bab613fd6e9156c2f0c/bin:/home/dziugas/.local/bin:/home/dziugas/.vscode-server/bin/fcac248b077b55bae4ba5bab613fd6e9156c2f0c/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle winteka@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /home/dziugas/winteka
10 silly lifecycle winteka@1.0.0~dev: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'webpack --mode development --watch ./winteka/frontend/src/index.js --output ./winteka/frontend/static/frontend/main.js'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle winteka@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle winteka@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: winteka@1.0.0 dev: `webpack --mode development --watch ./winteka/frontend/src/index.js --output ./winteka/frontend/static/frontend/main.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid winteka@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/dziugas/winteka
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error winteka@1.0.0 dev: `webpack --mode development --watch ./winteka/frontend/src/index.js --output ./winteka/frontend/static/frontend/main.js`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the winteka@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

What can be wrong?
This is my script line in the package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch ./winteka/frontend/src/index.js --output ./winteka/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./winteka/frontend/src/index.js --output ./winteka/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  }
```

And the installed packages in the package.json file:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  }
```

In the past I have made few servers with the npm and node.js, I was using the same method and everything worked before. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a bit older version of webpack, so instead of `--output` you should use `--output-path`